# Удаление файлов в папке по дате Java (JSP)

Tags: java, html, jsp

Не получается удалить старые файлы в папке через JSP по дате. Имеется класс для удаления файлов  (DeleteFile.java) и два JSP. Первый JSP (index.jsp), основная страница, где имеется поле для ввода пути папки и поле для ввода количества дней (сколько дней назад был создан файл). Второй JSP (deletefile.jsp) должен выводить список файлов, которые были удалены.

P.S. И как добавить функцию удаления по определенному типу файла, допустим .txt.

DeleteFile.java

```
import java.io.File;

public class DeleteFile {

       public static void deleteFiles(String daysBack, String dirWay) {

           File f = new File(dirWay);
           if(f.isDirectory()){

               File[] listFiles = f.listFiles();  

               long timeAgo = System.currentTimeMillis() - (Integer.parseInt(daysBack) * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
               for(File listFile : listFiles) {
                   if(listFile.lastModified() < timeAgo) {
                       if(!listFile.delete()) {
                           System.err.println("Файл удален: " + listFile);
                       }
                   }
               }
           } else {
               System.out.println("Файлы не найдены");
           }
           }
       }
```

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page language="java"
       contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>mainpage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<center>Stub</center>
<br>

    <form action="deletefile.jsp" method="POST"  >
     Удалить файлы:  <input type="text" name="text" >
     Создан дней назад:  <input type="number" name="timeago">
                        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
                          </form>
</body>
</html>
```

deletefile.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><%@page language="java"contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page import="ru.sbrf.asfs.stub.stubsUtils.DeleteFile"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%     DeleteFile delfile = new DeleteFile();

String fileName = request.getParameter("text");
String timeAgo = request.getParameter("timeago");

delfile.deleteFiles(timeAgo, fileName);


  %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Deletepage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте больше логать, например выдавать все файлы которые проверяются

```
for(File listFile : listFiles) {
  System.out.println("checking file: " + listFile.getAbsolutePath() + "; lastModified=" + listFile.lastModified());
  // etc
```

PS: фильтровать файлы можно с помощью FileFilter или FilenameFilter

```
File[] listFiles = f.listFiles(path -> path.getName().endsWith(".txt"));
```